# Kafka client and aggregated events

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, event-driven, event-driven-design

In event-driven design we strive to find out events that we interested of. Using Kafka we can easily subscribe (a new `group.id`) to a topic and start consuming events. If retention policy is default one we could consume also one week old messages if specify `auto.offset.reset=earliest`. Right? But what if we want to start from the **very beginning**? I guess that *KTable* should be used but I'm not sure what will happened when a new client has subscribed to a stateful stream. Could you tell me is it true that the new subscriber will receive all aggregated messages?

Answer (score 0):

You can't consume data that has been deleted.

That's why KTables are built on top of compacted topics, which will store the latest keys for each record, and have infinite retention.

If you want to read the "current state" of the table, to get all aggregated messages, then you can use [Interactive Queries](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/streams/developer-guide/interactive-queries.html).

> not sure what will happened when a new client has subscribed to a stateful stream

It needs to read the entire compacted topic, starting from the beginning (earliest available offset, not necessarily the first ever produced message) since it cannot easily find where in the topic that each unique key may start.

Comment: If I have `KTable<K, V> aggregate = ..collect data..;  aggregate.toStream(..).to(serdeK, serdeV, "aggregated-data");`. Does the new client will receive all aggregated messages if it has subscribed to `aggregated-data` topic?

Comment: No, it gets a stream of updates to the table. That consumer will need to de-dupe the keys itself.